# How to get Description of MySQL Table in GoLang

Tags: go, go-gorm

com/jinzhu/gorm" and "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" package to interact with my database and trying to get the description of table but didn't found the function. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **gorm** you can perform a custom query and get her return in a **struct**, the following is an example of how to show the description of table:

```
type Result struct {
    Field    string
    Type     string
    Null     string
    Key      string
    Default  string
    Extra    string
}

db.Raw("DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME").Scan(&result)
```

View more by gorm:
http://jinzhu.me/gorm/advanced.html#sql-builder